# Show that $|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem is : if $z$ lies on a circle with diameter having endpoints $z_1$ and $z_2$ then show that $|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$ where $z, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

The angle subtended by the diameter on any point on the circle is a right angle and thus $|z-z_1|$, $|z-z_2|$ and $|z_1-z_2|$ are the lengths of a right-angled triangle. The equation above then follows from the Pythagorean Theorem.

Now the equation for $z$ can also be written as $\left|z - \left(\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)\right| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}$ since $\left(\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$ is the centre and $\dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}$ is the radius of the circle.

But since the locus of both the equations are the same, I figured that it should be possible to prove them equal. So here's what I did:

$$\begin{align}
\left|z - \left(\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)\right| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2} &\iff |2z - (z_1+z_2)| =|z_1-z_2| \\
&\iff |(z - z_1)+ (z-z_2)|^2=|z_1-z_2|^2 \end{align}$$

Using $|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + \Re{(z_1\overline{z_2})}$,

$|z - z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2  + \Re{((z-z_1)\overline{(z-z_2)})}=|z_1-z_2|^2$. Comparing it with what I have to show, it seems like I have to prove $\Re{((z-z_1)\overline{(z-z_2)})} =  0$, but I can't think of a way of doing that.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** To sum it up, my question is how to show that $$\left|z - \left(\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)\right| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}\iff|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$$ $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$where $z, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comment, the question seems to be

> If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are at different ends of the diameter of a circle, and $z$ is also on that circle, prove
>   $$
> \mathrm{Re}((z-z_1)(\overline{z-z_2}))=0
> $$

**Method 1:** One way to see this is to note that $\mathrm{Re}(z\bar{w})=z\cdot w$ (dot product as vectors). Since $z-z_1$ and $z-z_2$ are perpendicular, $(z-z_1)\cdot(z-z_2)=0$.

**Method 2:** Another way of looking at this, is to let $c$ be the center of the circle and let $w=z-c$, $w_1=z_1-c$, and $w_2=z_2-c$. Then $w_2=-w_1$ and $|w|=|w_1|=|w_2|=r$
$$
\begin{align}
(z-z_1)(\overline{z-z_2})
&=(w-w_1)(\overline{w-w_2})\\
&=w\bar{w}+w_1\bar{w}_2-w\bar{w}_2-\bar{w}w_1\\
&=w\bar{w}-w_1\bar{w}_1+(w\bar{w}_1-\bar{w}w_1)\\
&=r^2-r^2+2i\,\mathrm{Im}(w\bar{w}_1)\\
&=2i\,\mathrm{Im}(w\bar{w}_1)
\end{align}
$$
which is pure imaginary. Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{Re}((z-z_1)(\overline{z-z_2}))=0
$$

Comment: I know that this can be shown using this theorem. I'm trying to prove that $|z - (\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2})| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}$ is the same as $|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$. I think my question is unclear.

Comment: I think your question's clear, @Alraxite : what you want in your comment and also in the comment below my answer is what is unclear since you did **not** ask this equivalence...which, as already pointed out below my answer, is trivial.

Comment: @Alraxite: I hope this more closely addresses your question.

Answer (score 2):

If $z=x+iy,z_k=x_k+iy_k$ for $k=1,2$

the real part of $(z-z_1)(\overline{z-z_2})$ is $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)$

Using Article $145$ [The elements of coordinate geometry](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00loneuoft) by Loney

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

WLOG suppose we have the circle $|z|=r\;$ and that $\,z_1=-r\;,\;\;z_2=r\;,\;z=re^{it}\;,\;\;0<t<\pi\;$ , then

$$|z-z_1|^2+|z-z_2|^2=|r(\cos t+1)+ir\sin t|^2+|r(\cos t-1)+i\sin t|^2=$$

$$=r^2(\cos^2t+2\cos t+1)+r^2\sin^2t+r^2(\cos^2t-2\cos t+1)+r^2\sin^2t=$$

$$=4r^2=|z_1-z_2|^2$$

Comment: But how does this show $|z - (\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2})| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2} \iff |z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking in your comment, @Alraxite : I addressed and answered you post's title, which is the right side of the expression you wrote in your comment above...but after taking a peek at it I think your left side is trivial: it says the distance from $\,z\,$ to the circle's center equals the circle's radius...which, again, is trivial since $\;z\;$ belongs to the circle!

Comment: Let me explain. The problem is 'if $z$ lies on a circle with diameter having endpoints $z_1$ and $z_2$ then show that $|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$ where $z, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$'. The part '$z$ lies on a circle with diameter having endpoints $z_1$ and $z_2$' is the same as saying $\left|z - \left(\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)\right| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}$ for obvious reasons. So the new problem I was trying to solve was the one that I stated in my first comment.

Comment: Please note that I use no other assumptions. That is, I'm trying to prove $ |z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = |z_1 - z_2|^2$ using only the information provided by $|z - (\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{2})| = \dfrac{|z_1-z_2|}{2}$. The point is: I've changed the original assumption given in the problem to this. Anyway, I do appreciate your answer since it shows me a different way to solve the original problem.